# How to pass in field of undefined to children as props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Sorry, JS noob here. In angularJS we are able to pass in a value into `ng-model` even if it is `undefined`, can we achieve the samething in reactJS? For example, let say I have a `Developer` component that calls a custom `MyInput`:

Developer:

```
export class DeveloperPage extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       this.state = {
          developer: {}
       }
   }
   
   render() {
        return (
            <MyInput value={this.state.developer.company.name} />
            // TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined (because company is undefined)
        )
   }
}
```

Here I want to pass in `this.state.developer.company.name` even though `company` here doesn't exist yet, but will exist later.

MyInput:

```
export class MyInput extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    valueExists = ???;
    
    return (
      <input 
        value={valueExists ? value : ""}
        {...rest} 
        className="my-input"></input>
    )
  }
}
```

Here I wish to check that the value exists.

This is doable in angularJS as you can just pass in any field directly whether its nestings are `undefined` or not. Like this

```
<input ng-model="state.developer.level1.level2.level3.name">
```

If each level is defined then it binds to the value, otherwise it is just empty, it will not throw a error.

If this is not achievable I wish to know why and what's the differnce in nature of reactJS vs angularJS that prevents this behavior. So i can better understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with react. It is completely related to JavaScript in general. As you're trying to access a property on an object which doesn't exist, it is normal to receive an error. You have a few options to solve your problem:

1. Add the properties in the initial state like so:

   ```js
   this.state = {
       developer: {
           company: {}
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use the [Optional chaining operator [?.]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to safely navigate through nested objects:

   ```html
   <MyInput value={this.state.developer?.company?.name} />
   ```

   This will pass `undefined` to `MyInput` if any of the `?.` suffixed properties is missing.
3. Check for the variable state before passing it to the child component:

   ```html
   <MyInput value={this.state.developer?.company?.name ?? ''} />
   ```

   This will pass an empty string to `MyInput` if any of the `?.` prefixed properties is missing or the `name` itself is `undefined`/`null`.

Option 2 should be best suited for your case, I guess, as it allows for greatest flexibility.

Comment: in angularJS you can do <input ng-model="state.developer.level1.level2.level3.name"> without throwing an error. if all the nestings exists, then it would binding to name, otherwise the value is just empty until binded. Do you think this can be achieved in javascript?

Comment: @andyh0316 I am pretty sure you're mistaken about angular's behaviour. Or at least the last time I used the framework this wasn't the case and it doesn't sound right in general. Can you provide a working example of that with angular? You can't bind to something that doesn't exist before creating it first. In any case, the second option is the way to go for you in react.

Comment: I edited my example in the question. But aynways, i think your second option is perfect for what i need. Thank you very much =)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `undefined` in javascript just like you can in typescript. The problem here is accessing the `name` property of an already undefined property: `this.state.developer.company.name`. In other words, you would be able to pass `this.state.developer.company` despite the fact that it's still undefined. Trying to get `name` though will throw an error.

Addressing `DeveloperPage` first.

```
...
return (
          <MyInput value={this.state.developer.company ? this.state.developer.company.name : ''} />

        )
```

Then in `MyInput`:

```
...
const { value } = this.props;

    return (
      <input 
        value={value ? value : ""}
        {...rest} 
        className="my-input"></input>
    )
```

Comment: Is it possible to not do the this.state.developer.company ? ... check?? Say I have multiple levels of nestings and 100 fields on a page. It would be troublesome to do this.state.developer.level1.name or this.state.developer.level1.level2.level3.name.. I know I am asking for alot, but since this is doable in angularJS, and if it is not doable in reactJS i would like to know why so that can help me better understand the nature of reactJS.